# Keyword argument (kwargs) function error in Python

Tags: python

Following is the code:

```
def my_funct(**kwarg):
    print(kwarg[fn]*kwarg[sn])
print('enter 2 numbers to get product of')
a=input()
print('enter second number')
b=input()
my_funct(fn=a,sn=b)
```

The output is error saying 'fn is not defined'. What is the solution?

Comment: _Don't_ use kwargs? Your function requires exactly two parameters.

Comment: `print(kwarg['fn'] * kwarg['sn'])`. You will also want to convert the input to `int.

Comment: but I was just practicing kwargs concept,that's why.

Comment: You don't practice the concept of screwdrivers by whacking nails with one. If you want practice with kwargs, do something where using kwargs makes sense.

Comment: I disagree, it makes total sense to start off with an example that is as simple as possible. That will necessarily be an example where kwargs is overkill.

Comment: @yagod: It's not overkill. That's like saying a square peg is overkill for a round hole. It's just the wrong tool for the job. `def my_funct(**kwarg)` says that this function takes arbitrary keyword arguments, when the actual desired behavior isn't like that at all.

Comment: I think you're missing the point. He is trying to wrap his head around the concept of how kwargs works, what the syntax is like, etc. The job is irrelevant, it's about understanding the basics of the tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kwargs is a dictionary where the variable name is the key and has type `str`. You are trying to find the value to the key which is saved in the variable `fn` but this variable hasn't been defined. Instead what you want is the value corresponding to the key `'fn'`, so you do

```
print(kwarg['fn'] * kwarg['sn'])
```

Edit: Because your corresponding values come from the `input()` function, you should make sure they are actually numbers and not strings. So when you do `a=input()` you should change that to `a=float(input())`. Same for `b`.